# How to make a web request wait for a particular interval?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, restlet

I have created a Restlet service containing a GET method. When a call occurs on this GET method I want the request to wait until one of my boolean variable becomes true. (I think timer is not a good solution, since it is asynchronous). Any function available on GWT?

Comment: What's this boolean variable? Where does it come from? What if the boolean variable becomes true on another GAE instance than the one where the request is waiting? The request will timeout after 30 seconds, are you aware of that? Do you know tha threading is restricted on GAE? What's the more general objective of this?

Comment: Boolean variable is from a static class. Actually this a simple way of communication between 2 clients. Also Iam aware of that time out. I want this checking only for 10seconds. If still that variable is false, I will consider this as a noresponse(offline) from that client.

Comment: bad idea. There is no guarantee that each user gets the same instance. Communication between two clients must go through some persistent store.

Comment: @fdreger is right - though persistence isn't necessarily required, since you could use backends. The bigger problem here is that blocking takes up instance time, which will cost you money. Using the channel API is a much better (and more affordable) idea.

Comment: Wright,ChannelAPI seems to be a better solution. But consider this situation:My clients are an Android device & a C# Client running on PC. How can I use those google channel libraries on these clients(mainly on C#)?Or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this, then simply make the access to the boolean variable synchronized, and wait for 10 seconds:

```
private static boolean status;

private final Object lock = new Object();

public void setStatus(boolean newStatus) {
    synchronized(lock) {
        this.status = newStatus;
        if (this.status) {
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}

public boolean getTrueStatusOrBlock() throws InterrupedException {
    synchronized(lock) {
        if (status) {
            return true;
        }
        lock.wait(10000L);
        return status;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will not work, because you cannot ensure that different requests use the same instance.

Comment: I agree, and warned the OP in my first comment to his question.

Comment: Your answer has no such disclaimer, though. I'm not sure I see the point in posting an answer that definitely won't work.